# Laravel 5.4 Vue Declarative Rendering

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.4

In a laravel 5.4 environment I want to render the text "Example" in the `.panel-heading` of **Example.vue**. After doing `npm run watch` I get the following Vue warn:

*'Property or method "message" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option.'*

**app.js**

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      message: 'Example'
    }
});
```

**Example.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" >{{ message }}</div>

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        I'm an example component!
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

**app.blade.php**

```
<html>
<!-- ... -->
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <example></example>
  </div>
  <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your Example.vue component doesn't have access to its parent's properties. You need to either add `message` as a data property in your Example component or pass it in as a prop from the parent.

Comment: You mean like this : `Vue.component('example',{props:['message']}, require('./components/Example.vue'));`? Can you specify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Example.vue component doesn't have access to its parent's properties. You need to define `message` within the same scope of the component you are trying to use it in.

You can do this by adding `message` as a data property in your Example component:

```
// Example.vue script
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      message: 'Example',
    }
  },
}
```

Or you can pass it in as a prop:

```
// Example.vue script
export default {
  props: ['message'],
}
```

In your case, you would pass a value for the `message` prop like this:

```
// in app.blade.php
<example message="Example"></example>
```

Here's the documentation on [Vue Component props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Props).

Comment: Only the first example is working. Can I send the data from my **app.js** ?

Comment: No, because you do not have an instance of your Example component in `app.js`, you're only registering it there. Props get passed as an attribute on the component's tag. See the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Props).

Comment: The second example should be working, are you getting the same error or a different one?

Comment: No sorry, It Is working. I though there were three different examples. Now I have it right. Thanks!